# Failure in maven site plugin version 3?

Tags: maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I am trying to get a project to run the maven site:site goal using Maven 3.0.4. Unbeknownst to me, it had been running under Maven 2.2.1 (when I thought it should have been 3).

I keep getting the following failure:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-cli) on project myproj-parent: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.

How do I even find what artifact is missing groupId?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the POM file for one of my dependencies was corrupt. The POM for joda-jsptags-1.0.2 in our Nexus repository wasn't a POM, but a fragment of HTML.

Getting a clean version of joda-jsptags fixed this issue.

It was just frustrating not to get any sort of idea what was bad. And apparently the Maven 3 plugins are more strict on POM parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from Maven 2.2.1 to Maven 3.0.4 you have to be aware of some difference in particular in relation with site generation. You should have taken a look the the [migration docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#Using_maven-site-plugin_2.x_with_Maven_2_and_maven-site-plugin_3.x_with_Maven_3) and take a look if your pom needed to be fixed.

Missed a [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html).